# How to add quotes to aliases in generated sql via Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Due to the database(snowflake) I am using , I have to quote the alias names generated by the hibernate.

Hibernate generates as below for an example

```
select emp0_.emp_id as emp_id1_0_0_, emp0_.name as name_2_0_0_ from test.employee emp0_ where emp0_.emp_id=?
```

But I want to quote the alias/identifiers as

```
select emp0_.emp_id as "emp_id1_0_0_", emp0_.name as "name_2_0_0_" from test.employee emp0_ where emp0_.emp_id=?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your *actual* question about quoting aliases, but it may be a solution to the JPA+Snowflake casing problem, since we had the same issue and looked for the same solution.

If you are using the [Snowflake JDBC](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc) library, adding `&CLIENT_RESULT_COLUMN_CASE_INSENSITIVE=true` to the end of your Snowflake connection string the will allow the library to function with JPA/Hibernate. Make sure you are using the [Latest Snowflake JDBC](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/releases/latest), due to some bugs in the earlier versions causing the connection string to be changed from `jdbc:snowflake://` to `https://` at runtime.

Setting that connection property will cause [this](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeResultSetMetaData.java#L96) `columnName.toUpperCase()` code to trigger and the `getColumnIndex()` method will now work.

Additional information outside the scope of your question: When we set our spring application.properties like the following, we were able to use a PagingAndSortingRepository without needing our own DataSource or any additional configuration classes.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=[empty class extending org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
spring.datasource.username=${snowflake.user}
spring.datasource.password=${snowflake.password}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:snowflake://${snowflake.account}.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=${snowflake.warehouse}&db=${snowflake.databaseName}&schema=${snowflake.schema}&CLIENT_RESULT_COLUMN_CASE_INSENSITIVE=true
```