# snowflake returning uppercase fields resultset that causes issues jpql mapping jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jpql

I have a project to do integration with snowflake database using ORM like JPA/Hibernate
but for the resultset from snowflakes always returns fields in UPPERCASE which conflicts with JPQL default behevior.

Example below is a select query using JPQL as you can see all fields are in lowercase

```
select podioitem0_.ID as id1_0_0_, podioitem0_.JSON as json2_0_0_ from INLIFE_MARK.PUBLIC.podio_item podioitem0_ where podioitem0_.ID=?
```

The Resultset from snowflake returns Uppercase columns

[image: The Resultset from snowflake returns]

Given the samples above I get this error

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column not found: json2_0_0_
```

Its because when trying to map `json2_0_0_` column from resultset the mapper cant find it because the columns from resultset are on uppercase.

So Question, is there a way to tell JPQL or jpa/hibernate to generate the JPQL query in Uppercase? at least for the column names so I hope it would look like this?

```
select podioitem0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, podioitem0_.JSON as JSON2_0_0_ from INLIFE_MARK.PUBLIC.podio_item podioitem0_ where podioitem0_.ID=?
```

Additional details below

properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-                
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-    
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Sample Entity Class

```
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "INLIFE_MARK", name = "podio_item")
public class PodioItem {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "json", columnDefinition="varbinary")
    public byte[] json;
}
```

I am using CrudRepository to save and find objects

```
@Repository
public interface PodioItemRepository extends        
           CrudRepository<PodioItem, Long> {
}
```

I was hoping maybe somekind of property as a solution but any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This looks like a driver problem, speaking of which, why are you using SQL Server dialect given that your database is Snowflake?

Comment: you can put double quotes "columnName" to force the output how you need it.

Comment: Hi @SimeonPilgrim I am using CrudRepository, let me update the details

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hey yup I use it initially because it works but Im not sure to what extent, do you have the correct driver for snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [How to add quotes to aliases in generated sql via Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446111/how-to-add-quotes-to-aliases-in-generated-sql-via-hibernate)

Just add `&CLIENT_RESULT_COLUMN_CASE_INSENSITIVE=true` to your snowflake connection string.